# React Native error: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: object

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am getting this error and I am having a lot of trouble fixing this.

What I am trying to do here is have 3 different screens and have a tabbar that navigates to each screen.

Here is my index:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Navigator, StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';

import Nav from './app/components/Nav';
import Screen from './app/Screen';

import Tabs from 'react-native-tabs'

import SwitchView from './SwitchView';

class Proj extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
}

render(){
    var x = "FeedView";
    return(

          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Tabs selected={x} style={{backgroundColor:'white'}}
                  selectedStyle={{color:'red'}} onSelect={el=> {x = el.props.name}}>
                <Text name="FeedView">First</Text>
                <Text name="WikiView" selectedIconStyle={{borderTopWidth:2,borderTopColor:'red'}}>Second</Text>
                <Text name="BoardView">Third</Text>
            </Tabs>

            <SwitchView id={x}/>

          </View>
    );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
},
welcome: {
fontSize: 20,
textAlign: 'center',
margin: 10,
},
instructions: {
textAlign: 'center',
color: '#333333',
marginBottom: 5,
},
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Proj', () => Proj);
```

here is my SwitchView:

```
import Feed from './app/pages/Feed/Feed';
import Board from './app/pages/Board';
import Wiki from './app/pages/Wiki';

class SwitchView extends Component {
render(){
    var { id } = this.props;

    switch (id) {
        case "FeedView":
            return <Feed/>
        case "WikiView":
            return <Wiki/>
        case "BoardView":
            return <Board/>
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 111):

**This is probably caused by some JS module export/import issues in your program, typically for one of the two reasons listed below:**

- You forget to export, or you export something incorrectly
- You import something that doesn't exist, or you import something incorrectly

I ran into similar error, but in my case, it is not caused by `export` but caused by `import`, and I used the `import` statement incorrectly to import something that doesn't exist in the module.

In my case, the `import` was incorrectly written as:

`import { MyComponent } from './MyComponents/MyComponent'`

while actually it should be:

`import MyComponent from './MyComponents/MyComponent'`

And it drove me crazy and took me a whole day to figure it out and I hope this will save several hours for some people.

Comment: I had this issue too. I learned that it depends on how MyComponent is exported. When you put 'export default MyComponent;' then the import is without {}. When you don't use the default keyword in the export, then you need to surround the component name with {}, i.e. { MyComponent }.

Comment: Same here I just removed Curly braces in my import

Comment: In my case i needed to change "import * as Fork" to "import Fork"

Comment: I was getting this error when using `navigate` function when trying to route. Adding "{ }' to my imports resolved it . Like `import {samplePage} from './samplePage';` and the export was like this `export const samplePage = () => {...}`

Answer (score 26):

Change your SwitchView definition to

`export default class SwitchView extends Component...`

Comment: @Parkicism you should accept this if it was your answer. It also looks like the first one to answer correctly.

Answer (score 9):

Modify your SwitchView to this:

```
import Feed from './app/pages/Feed/Feed';
import Board from './app/pages/Board';
import Wiki from './app/pages/Wiki';
export default class SwitchView extends Component {
render(){
    var { id } = this.props;

    switch (id) {
        case "FeedView":
            return <Feed/>
        case "WikiView":
            return <Wiki/>
        case "BoardView":
            return <Board/>
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I faced this issue only for the packages installed.
Previously I wrote as

```
import WebView from 'react-native-webview-messaging/WebView';
```

I changed to

```
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview-messaging/WebView';
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue when i wrote :

`import {ErrorMessage} from '../Components/ErrorMessage';`

instead of writing like this :

`import ErrorMessage from '../Components/ErrorMessage';`

Answer (score 3):

In my vase I was on react-native `0.46.4` and had something like `import MainContainer from './app'` where the `app` directory had a shared `index.js` file amongst Android and iOS, but React Native wasn't detecting an `index.js` inside `app`. Once I switched to `import MainContainer from './app/index.js'` it worked.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me on RN 0.42.3. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

this error can be resolved by using Defualt

instead of  **export** use  **export default**

Comment: Thanks for the contribution Umer. Can you also please add a little description explaining your solution. Why do you think this will work, what makes you determine this is the solution. reading through these will help the OP understand their mistake better and be able to utilise your answer more effectively.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was with incorrectly npm installation of 'AppLoading'.
I got error "Component Exception: Element type is invalid" while using react-navigation.
There was advice statement below this error to check the render method of 'App'.
I had not installed 'AppLoading' properly. I then install it as:

```
expo install expo-app-loading
```

and then changed app loading import to

```
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";
```

[note: make sure that your `<AppLoading />` should contain onError prop].
Making these simple changes my app started working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error gets fixed by checking the versions of react-navigation and react-navigation/drawer

I was having the @react-navigation version 5
and having the @react-navigation/drawer version 6 and this was causing the issue.

I removed the version 6
and then installed the @react-navigation/drawer version 5 and the issue was fixed

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem I have to update all my navigation/stack and drawer to be on the latest versions all of them

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue

```
import Something from '@library';
```

Just changed to

```
import { Something } from '@library';
```

and vice verse

Comment: This has already been mentioned in some other answers.

Answer (score 1):

I handled the same problem as your error is saying that your component is invalid which is  **SwitchView** you are returning this component as object checkitout.

hope this hint helped you i  am new in stackoverflow so not familiar with answer tab
thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

How is that different from module.exports = SwitchView?

For me module.exports works for all of my js files except one.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by some JS module export/import issues in your program, typically for one of the two reasons listed below:

1. You forget to export or you export something incorrectly
2. You import something that doesn't exist or you import something incorrectly

I ran into similar error, but in my case it was not caused by export, but rather import. I used the import statement incorrectly to import something that doesn't exist in the module.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when you are trying to access a component which is not exported. In my case, I forgot to export a component and I was accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case  I had replaced

```
const App: () => React$Node = () => {
```

in app.js this line with

```
const App = () => {
```

and it's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

İn My Case I implement rafce Command and  Then Somehow  Forgot to Export the App.js

```
const App = () =>  {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown : false}} initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={Home}/>
        <Stack.Screen name='Details' component={Details}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And then I realized that I haven't add the Export .
Then I changed My code into this and it worked Fine:

```
const App = () =>  {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown : false}} initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={Home}/>
        <Stack.Screen name='Details' component={Details}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```