# Importing a class and returning a view not working

Tags: react-native

I've tried importing a property from a class and it worked when i created the class withing the same file, however when importing it from an outside js file I get a 'Element type invalid: expecting a string but got an object' error. Thanks for any help.

```
export class Setting extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <Image source={{uri: 'https://someimage.png/>
    );
  }
}

import {Setting} from '../Settings.js'
export default class MainScreen extends Component {
  render() { 
    return (
        <View>
            <Setting/>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey pretty sure this is a duplicate question, here's a similar one: [React Native error: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37620473/react-native-error-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string-or-a-class-functi)

But this should fix your problem, hopefully.

```
export default class Settings extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <Image source={{uri: 'https://someimage.png/>
    );
  }
}

import Settings from '../Settings.js'
export default class MainScreen extends Component {
  render() { 
    return (
        <View>
            <Setting/>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see I changed the way your `import` was working previously and added `default` to your export for your class and also kept your class name consistent to the `JavaScript` file.

Comment: I was importing a component from react-native that was missing {}. So I had import Image from react native and not import {image} from react native. But I needed to know I had the right idea so your post definitely helped. Thank you!